# Finding the association between dispatch queues and pthreads

Tags: ios, pthreads, grand-central-dispatch

I have been trying to find an association between pthreads on iOS and dispatch queues. For example, given a `pthread_t` object, is it possible to figure out the associated dispatch queue, if any?

I have seen all sorts of `*get_current_*()` or `*get_specific_*()` APIs -- all of them are useful only when I am aware of the previously used keys to set the context, or I already have a `dispatch_queue_t` corresponding to the dispatch queue whose label I want.

All I am looking for is to get a list of all the dispatch queues (private/serial ones -- created
within an application), so that somehow I can get the `dispatch_queue_t` object and
thereby use those to find the associations with the threads of that application process
and hence print their names.

**EDIT(The solution I got after considering Das's suggestion - `thread_info()`)**: I got the dispatch queue names! I had to use `thread_info()` to get hold of `dispatch_qaddr` of each thread. Then, I treated the content of `dispatch_qaddr` which is of type `uint64_t`, to be of type `(dispatch_queue_t *)` and dereferenced as needed to pass to `dispatch_queue_get_label()` to get the label. The **trick** here is to check in a safe manner whether a thread at a given point in time is executing a dispatch queue's block of code or not. Otherwise, the internal operations done by `dispatch_queue_get_label()` on the object we pass might crash the application. So, I had to use some platform specific API to verify the validity of the resulting object's content to be proper being of size: `sizeof(dispatch_queue_t)`, given that `dispatch_queue_t` is an opaque type. Yeah, I am happy to see what I wanted! Cheers! \m/

Comment: What code experiments have you done so far?

Comment: 1) Used the API to get the main-queue label and on the same lines, I tried and tried, and have been trying to figure out a way to tell, "Okay, this thread has a dispatch queue associated with it". But, not being possible so far. 2) Looked up the open source libdispatch library source code. Apart from these, my above question summarizes by research so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get a list of all the dispatch queues in a process is via heap traversal, e.g. using the `heap` tool:

> $ heap -addresses OS_dispatch_queue MyApp

or a programmatic equivalent implemented via the malloc introspection API, c.f. `malloc/malloc.h`.

This is because idle/suspended queues are really just objects in memory that are only tracked by whoever created them/has references to them, there is no central "registry" of queues.

There is a facility to find the running queues currently associated to threads, but it is ONLY suitable for use by debuggers, crashreporters and the like, c.f. `mach/thread_info.h`:

The `thread_identifier_info` structure obtained from `thread_info(thread, THREAD_IDENTIFIER_INFO, ...)` contains a `dispatch_qaddr` field with the queue currently associated to the (mach) thread in question.

Please realize that unless the thread being inspected in this manner is suspended (as would be the case when a debugger is using that call), the information that you obtain from this API will be stale immediately (the thread could already have switched to process another queue), and the queue pointer returned may be dangling (if the queue owner has deallocated it in the meantime).

In general there is no safe/useful way to use the `thread_info` API or the malloc introspection API mentioned above from inside a running process to introspect its own threads resp. heap, these APIs are intended purely for use by out-of-process debugging tools.

Comment: Okay, seems interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: And I got the dispatch queue names! The details are updated at the end of my above question itself to help in locating the answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no fixed association between threads and queues.  GCD manages a pool of threads and generally any thread can run a block from any queue.  The only exception is that the main queue always runs its blocks on the main thread, and the main thread only runs blocks from the main queue.

There is no API to ask “which queue is running on some other thread” because the answer might change the instant after you ask.  Inside a dispatched block, you can ask for the current queue, and thus know what queue is running on the current thread, but that answer can become invalid as soon as that block returns.

Comment: Yeah, I got to know from other discussions that there is no one-to-one mapping between threads(pthreads, specifically) and dispatch queues. However, I just want to know at any instant whether a thread is executing a some dispatch queue's block of code or not -- this may or may not change immediately after my check. But, it's fine, I don't need that accuracy. In addition, my code is not intended to run as part of any thread's execution so that I could use one of the *get_current_queue*() sort of APIs.

Comment: Continued: All I have is a set of pthread_t information of all the threads of an application. Using that, I am supposed to find out whether each of the thread is executing a dispatch queue's block of code at a given point in time.

Comment: «...the main thread only runs blocks from the main queue.» Blocks dispatched synchronously from the main thread to any queue may run on the main thread or, in general, any `dispatch_sync()` may run its task on the thread where it originated.